# Can I use a landline ADSL with a fast satellite DSL feed to overcome the latency issue of satellite?

Tags: networking, internet

My satellite ADSL provides up to 20mbps, but it has a latency of 700ms. Can I use a slow fixed-line ADSL plus the Satellite dsl feed together, with a dual band router, so that the fixed ADSL deals with latency issue, but data download comes through the Sat DSL?

I have read that it's not possible to combine the downloads to increase download speed, but that's not what I'm after. I just want to overcome the latency problem with satellite.

I have seen many dual wan, load balancing routers for sale, but does anyone have a specific recommendation for this application?

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: I don't remember which one, but some satellite company at least used to offer down-link via satellite, up-link via DSL (possibly wildblue, I don't see this on their page now however).   I think that the connection to work correctly would need to be provided by the same provider.  At the time, I think the biggest complaint was that the people that wanted that service couldn't get it, and if they could get DSL to begin with why would they want satellite at all.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Let me explain by telling you how this works.

What is latency? Latency is the time it takes for a packet to go from the source to the target and back.

When you use a satellite connection, you send data through a satellite in orbit which then relays your data to another satellite on the ground before your data is sent to its final destination. The trip to the orbital satellite and back again is what causes the huge delay (latency) to appear.

But its not just a ping that tells the latency, it is the entire data stream. So once you initiate a data stream, all packets will follow that route, so your latency is high all the time. If you'd route traffic through your land line, all would follow that path.

So you cannot make data split and expect things to work as expected. Either it goes fast, but with a high latency, or it goes slow with a low latency.

There are ways to route different kinds of traffic to different wan ports which might get you a very little boost, but I doubt it would get the result you'd expect.